# How to post an input value in a form, inside a specified div?

Tags: c#, html, post

I have a form:

```
    <div id="header_box" class="header_box header_text_box" onclick="stop(event)">
         <form onsubmit="return false;" id="reedem_reward">
             <input type="text" id="code" placeholder="enter code">
             <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>
    </div>
```

Im trying to send a value to this form, but I dont really know how to get this work. I tried with this:

```
    //To get value:
    string codevalue=Request.Form["code"];

   // To set value:
    code.Value="ABCD";
```

Comment: Your question is lacking in information. What kind of list do you want to give value from? If you want to submit the form, why do you return `false` from `onsubmit` handler? Does the website already give you a message box? What kind of response do you want to get?

Comment: Its just a list, fullfilled with strings, especially codes. I read out this html code while debugging the website, and I just copied it, maybe its not possible, if this return false? It didnt give any message box, it will, if I enter a code. The response would be the texts inside the message box.